# What causes P300, P301, P303 and P304 after driving several miles? 1999 Accord 2.3l

Tags: honda, accord, misfire

I have replaced the spark plugs, which were oily, cleaned the tubes, replaced tube seals (which were cracked), and have not seen oil leaks since, but the misfires persist. The wires are fourteen months old. I do not see any damage and I checked them with a multimeter. The distributor was leaking oil and the points were corroded. I replaced it, but the misfires continue. What do I check next to stop my car's cylinders from misfiring?  Thank you very much!  Have a great day! :)

Comment: Check the compression in each cylinder with a wet and dry test

Comment: Or you could do a Morse test...

Comment: You replaced the points in the distributor? The distributor in question is electronic ... no points in there, so I'm wondering what you actually replaced? The coil is built into the distributor, which is a weird arrangement, but not excessively so. Also, you don't get a P0302 code? How did you check your spark plug wires? Which plugs did you use?

Comment: Did you verify ignition timing was set properly after Dist replacement?

Comment: Have you verified proper voltage feeding the distributor?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not checking back!  Mechanics always say that DIYers are bad for throwing parts at a problem, they need a mechanic to properly diagnose it.  Well, after doing everything that I could to diagnose it, I replaced the wires anyway.
The misfires went away!
Thanks for your feedback! :)